# Insert Data within a loop and echo only once

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, foreach

i have a php script with a sql query that is inside a foreach loop and if the query succeed to run it should echo "Success" but since its inside a loop it echo "success" multiple times but i wish to only echo "success" once. I have seen other similar threads here and i have looked at those and tried solve my problem from those threads but i have not been able to solve this problem from any other threads so please dont mark this as a duplicate.

Anyway, Here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../config/dbconf.php');

foreach($_POST['entry'] as $entryid) {
  $stmt = $authconn->prepare("UPDATE account SET dp = dp - ? WHERE username = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST['price'], $_SESSION['classicusr']);
  if($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Success";
  }else{
    echo "Failed";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this?

Also, there is no need to prepare for each iteration of the loop.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../config/dbconf.php');


$bError = false;

$authconn->prepare("UPDATE account SET dp = dp - ? WHERE username = ?");       

foreach($_POST['entry'] as $entryid) {   

     $stmt = $stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST['price'], $_SESSION['classicusr']);

     try{

    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
      $bError = true;
      // optional break and do not process further
      // break;
      $stmt = $stmt->errorInfo()
    }

  }catch (PDOException Exception){
      $bError = true;
      // additional erorr logging here. Could add to a delimetered string to report on later   } }

echo ($bError ? 'Failure' : 'Success' );

?>
```

Comment: I had to do some edits to the post it was some error about catch (PDOException Exception)

Comment: But now it looks like all works. I just changed Exception to $Exception

Comment: good to hear. Glad it helped. You still want to catch a general Exception, maybe the correct syntax is `PDOException Exception $e? Also look note I've moved prepare

Comment: Yeah i have tested and it prints Success once only if the query succeed but i have not tried what happens if query fail yet. But that should work too i guess

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as you're not saying anything about the Failed statement, something like this might do the trick. All it requires is setting a simple flag.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../config/dbconf.php');

$feedbackGiven = FALSE;
foreach($_POST['entry'] as $entryid) {
  $stmt = $authconn->prepare("UPDATE account SET dp = dp - ? WHERE username = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("is", $_POST['price'], $_SESSION['classicusr']);
  if($stmt->execute()) {
    if (!$feedbackGiven)
    {
      echo "Success";
      $feedbackGiven = TRUE;
    }
  }else{
    echo "Failed";
  }
}
?>
```